# Which packages install Qt5 pkg-config files?

Tags: apt, package-management, qt, qt5, pkg-config

I need Qt5 .pc pkg-config file in order to compile [this](https://github.com/FreeSpacenav/spnavcfg) application.
Of course I can install the whole Qt5 dev environment using the official Qt online installer.

But I wonder if I can install some Ubuntu packages for the requires modules only (core, widget and gui) that include the *.pc files as well.

I tried installing `libqt5widget5` but it seems it does not provide the pc [file](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libqt5widgets5/filelist).
I also searched with `apt-cache search` but I found nothing relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the compiler is complaining of a specific missing file, you can search inside all packages at https://packages.ubuntu.com/ - scroll down to "Search the contents of packages"

[image: picture of packages.ubuntu.com]

Type in the exact file name, pick the release and it will tell you which package(s) you might find the file in.

Alternatively use `apt-file` (which isn't installed by default).

```bash
sudo apt install apt-file
sudo apt-file update
apt-file search Qt5XmlPatterns.pc
libqt5xmlpatterns5-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/Qt5XmlPatterns.pc
```

Comment: Great! I wasn't aware of this tool, thanks!